# Google tag manager is generating a 404 error on data-gtmsrc

Tags: console, google-tag-manager, console.log

There is an error coming from GTM itself and it is generating a 404 error on every single page it loads.
it looks like the code is missing a ">" in the opening script tag.
https://www.staycity.com
And you can see the error in the console.

Just to confirm. This error is not coming from any custom tag, trigger or variable, I believe it is coming from the GTM itself.

[image]

Comment: I think it is coming from one of the tag in the GoogleTagManager. This script not looks like GTM script.

Comment: I searched for all our GTM and there is no script error